# Time Travel movie with a scene in a control centre that shakes whenever the timeline changes

Tags: story-identification, movie

Looking for a movie about time travel, possibly made in the 80s. The only scene I remember is set in a control center. Every time there is a change in the timeline, the present adjusts which causes everything to shake like an earthquake.

Comment: Are you thinking about [Twelve Monkeys (1995)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_Monkeys)? Or maybe [Millennium(1989)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_(film))? You haven't provided much in the way of details.

Comment: No, I believe it's older than that and it wasn't a popular, high quality, well-known movie like Twelve Monkeys.

Comment: Please please tell me that they were called "*timequakes*"

Comment: YES! They were called "timequakes" and it was "Millennium." Thank you so much.

Comment: @Andi - Years of watching low-budget sci-fi flicks has given me an eye for the obvious lines. I'm assuming there was also some variation of the "*the problem isn't **where** these quakes are coming from, but **when**"*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'll guess [Millennium (1989)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_(film))¹. While definitely a second rate sci-fi flick (IMO), it featured two A-List actors of the time; [Kris Kristofferson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kris_Kristofferson) as Bill Smith and [Cheryl Ladd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheryl_Ladd) as Louise Baltimore.

[image] [image]

The plot centered around a time control center 1000 years in the future. They would send people from their own time back into the past to replace people destined for death in large scale disasters like airplane crashes.

Millenium movie information:

> Where has director Michael Anderson been since Logan's Run? Earning his keep on such slick TV-style time-fillers as Millennium. Kris Kristofferson plays the head of an official committee investigating the head-on collision of two commercial jets. A thorough analysis reveals the presence of a weapon of unknown origin in the wreckage; it is also pointed out that some of the victims' watches are running backwards. This, coupled with the cryptic warnings by flight attendant Cheryl Ladd to drop the investigation, prompts Kristofferson to burrow further and uncover the truth: Ladd is a sentinel from 1000 years in the future, who has come back to the 20th Century to help repopulate her dying civilization. Plot pegs and obstacles are in the hands of such sideline characters as enigmatic professor Daniel Travanti and amiable android Robert Joy. Millennium was adapted by John Varley from his own story Air Raid.
> <sub>*source:* [Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/millennium)</sub>

Abbreviated explanation for the time travel and [temporal incursions](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Temporal_incursion):

> Time travellers are visiting the present day and stealing passengers from doomed aircraft. In the future, because of pollution, the human population is no longer able to reproduce, so teams are sent in to the past to abduct groups of people who are about to die and keep them in stasis until they will be sent into the far future to repopulate the Earth. While many people in the future are in poor health, some are healthy enough to successfully pass for 20th Century humans, and are given the best of food and care so that they can successfully infiltrate, using reproductions of contemporary clothing.
>
> Every incursion into the past causes an accompanying "timequake" whose magnitude is proportional to the effects of the incursion. Each "timequake" causes physical damage in the time from which the incursion has been made. This is why they are abducting people who will not be able to affect the future any further and replacing them with copies of those who would have died.
> <sub>Excerpt from [Millenium (1989) Plot Summary](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097883/plotsummary)</sub>

I remember that it was all a little confusing the first time around. The people 1000 years in the future (circa 2989) are a sort of 'way station' when Earth's pollution has reached a point where all life is threatened. They pick up groups of healthy people from 1000 years ago (circa 1989) who are in imminent mortal danger from large scale disasters and keep them in stasis at their present time (circa 2989) in preparation to send them far into the future (circa 3989+) when the Earth has had a chance to recover and can once again support life long term.

The time control center would shudder or timequake² depending on the impact that these exchanges made on the timeline.

> In fact, the movie ends when a large timeline shift destroys the control centre in a massive timequake² event.

---

¹ <sub>The movie [Millennium (1989)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_(film)) should not be confused with the TV series [MillenniuM (1996-1999)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_(TV_series)).</sub>

² <sub>Despite the identical term, the use of 'timequake' should not be confused with [Timequake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timequake), a semi-autobiographical novel authored by Kurt Vonnegut, Jr. and published in 1997.</sub>

Comment: The John Varley novel that this was based on was much better. People had to chainsmoke to survive because their lungs had acclimatized to polluted air.

Comment: You got one point backwards: they raided past plane crashes and other disasters to bring the victims into their own time and harvest their organs.

Comment: @Spencer, I believe this is wrong. The purpose of bringing the would-be victims into the future was to repopulate the earth, not to harvest their organs.

Comment: @Spencer - I've refamiliarized myself with the plot and added some information.

Comment: @Spencer - You may be thinking of Freejack, where they were grabbing people from accidents so that they could 'jack' their bodies by giving them to rich elderly white people to brain-swap.

Comment: @Spencer IIRC the chain-smoking was adressed in the movie with a line like "You didn't smoke enough!" during the post-misson medical

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher - There was a juxtiposition between smoking and non-smoking attitudes of the 1980's. *'Present-day air is too clean for the time-travelers to process, so they must smoke cigarettes to replicate their accustomed atmosphere. In one scene, Smith and Baltimore (who, unbeknownst to him, is from the future) are **having dinner together and Baltimore smokes while eating**. Smith remarks, **"That is some habit you have there."** On returning to the future, her superior reprimands her that **she "didn't smoke enough"**.' *[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_(film)#Plot)

Comment: KK and CL were never quite A-list, I don't think.

Comment: Note: The movie is based on the novel [*Millennium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_\(novel\)) written by John Varley, who also wrote the movie script. The novel is based on a short story, "Air Raid", also written by Varley.

Comment: @releseabe - Granted that KK did a lot of schlock amongst some quality work and CL was primarily known as a TV actor/pop culture personality but they were both sought after personalities that drew crowds to whatever they were involved in. I would humbly suggest reading the bios that I provided links to for each of these celebrities; at least in the period of the mid 1980s to early 1990's.

Comment: @Jeeped: I certainly remember them from the old days and that itself implies that they were popular and maybe that is part of being an A-lister.